# Extract excel cell values of coloured cells

Tags: excel-formula, excel-2010, excel-2013

Want to copy all values of coloured cells in different sheets. Attaching the image for reference where I want to extract all values which have coloured cells [Excel sheetsample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/So60x.png)

Comment: afaik this can only be done using VBA

Comment: Yes, you need to use VBA to check the background colour of the cells. `Range("A1").Interior.ColorIndex = 3`, this for example would set the fill of A1 to red. Best to manually colour some cells in the colours you use, and record that action. Then you will get the correct ColorIndices.

Answer (score 0):

If you need this operation to be performed only once, you do not need to use vba. It would be easier to put filter on the top row (ctrl+shift+L), click the dropdown on the column and use filter by colour. Then you can easily mark all and copy/paste.